# Application Insights Java Agent: Which Certificates to add to truststore?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-insights

I'm getting the following error when starting my spring-boot application with the azure application-insights agent:

```
*************************
ApplicationInsights Java Agent failed to send telemetry data.
*************************
 
Description:
Unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
 
Action:
Please import the SSL certificate from https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/QuickPulseService.svc, into your custom java key store located at:
/truststore/truststore.jks
Learn more about importing the certificate here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2151450
```

This error only appears sometimes, sometimes it works.
It seems that different Azure Servers use different chains (+ root CA's).

My truststore contains the following Certs:

- Baltimore CyberTrust Root
- Microsoft RSA TLS CA 02
- Cert for live.applicationinsights.azure.com
- cert for in.applicationinsights.azure.com

I found the following [List of all Azure Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/azure-CA-details).

**Which Certificates from this list do I need to add to the truststore for the error to go away permanently?**

EDIT:
I've now added all the root certs from the page to my truststore, but I'm still getting the same error message. I do however see data in Azure Insights...

Comment: is there a reason you are not using the app insight agent instead? That way you don't need to modify your spring boot application but just provide the correct environment variables. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent

Answer (score 0):

*Try using application insight agent by which there is no need of modifying your spring boot application you only need to provide the correct environment variables*

*Here is the sample code for setting environment variables*

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = <Copy connection string from Application Insights Resource Overview>
```

*Else you can even set the environment variables by adding them in connecting string using applicationsettings.json file and below is the sample code for that*

```
{
  "connectionString": "Copy connection string from Application Insights Resource Overview"
}
```

*For the complete information regarding adding environment variables you can refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent) suggested by @Paizo.*